# Access ConfigurationDbContext outside startup

Tags: identityserver4

How can we access the same instance of ConfigurationDbContext outside the startup class after we configure it in the Startup.cs ?
I want to create a repository with ConfigurationDbContext and want to use the same instance of ConfigurationDbContext as configured in startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you could see in `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` [source code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/c59dea2399d22b57d3a9a7b750063b6bda5c1ad1/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Extensions/IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L28), `ConfigurationDbContext` is registered in built-in DI as `Scoped` (which actually means "per web request"). Moreover, it's also registered as implementation of `IConfigurationDbContext` interface.

To get access to `ConfigurationDbContext` instance, just inject it in your services via DI:

```cs
public MyService(IConfigurationDbContext context)
{
}

public HomeController(ConfigurationDbContext context)
{
}
```